# Microsoft Teams freeze on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, microsoft-teams

I am trying to run Microsoft `teams` on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop.

However, every time I try to launch the program, the entire system freezes and becomes completely unresponsive. I have to perform a hard shutdown by holding the power button.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by running

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft\ Teams/
```

Afterwards, Microsoft Teams starts as expected and does not crash the OS.

Comment: lol why on earth does this work

Comment: @JohnNyingi I got no damn idea, but I'm glad I could help someone :)

Comment: @Panki Could you please tell us where did you find this solution?

Comment: @Gustavo No, sorry - I figured this out on my own through trial and error.

Comment: @Panki But aren't those files created again and again?